# Svelte components with generics

Tags: typescript, svelte, typescript-generics, sveltekit, svelte-3

I want to use a generic type in a Svelte(Kit) component's props, and I found out there is this `type T = $$Generic` thing:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import type { Writable } from "svelte/store";
  type T = $$Generic;
  export let store: Writable<T[]>;
</script>
```

While that is great, I do need slightly more information than that: I require that the `T` has a property `id`. Normally I'd do something like this:

```js
export type WithId = { id: number };
function foo<T extends WithId>(property: T) { ... }
```

How can I do something similar for Svelte component props?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Edit:* The design was changed, generics should now be defined as an attribute which uses the regular `extends` keyword:

```html
<script lang="ts" generics="T extends { id: number }">
```

[RFC](https://github.com/dummdidumm/rfcs/blob/ts-typedefs-within-svelte-components/text/ts-typing-props-slots-events.md)

---

You can specify the type it extends like this:

```js
type T = $$Generic<{ id: number }>;
```

You can also use `type` or `interface` names, though if you define them within a component, you might have to place them in the module script, i.e. something like this:

```html
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    interface WithId { id: number }
</script>
<script lang="ts">
    export let store: Writable<T[]>;

    type T = $$Generic<WithId>;
</script>
```

Comment: this is pretty useful information. I could not find anything on svelte docs but it works. Should I open an issue for that?

Comment: @sryscad It's still not completely finalized, see [this](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442)

Comment: This isn't such an old question, so I'll try to answer a question: after defining `generics="T"`, how do I enter a value for it when calling the component?

Comment: @Lucas: It's derived from usage. E.g. if you have `export let value: T`, the `T` will be whatever you put in when specifying `<Component value={thing} />`.